# Image from my service keep getting error (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, amazon-s3, flutter-dependencies

I cannot display an image from a resource in Flutter, even though the URL is correct and I can view it without any issues. This issue is specific to this resource. but if I take an URL image from Google, it displays correctly.

this is my image url https://capture-bigmountain.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/upload/BYWHLKHLlmMgcZA89493205981758583.jpeg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZYRE.png)

I have tried using 'cached_network_image,' and it does not show any errors.
But when using 'NetworkImage,' I get the following error:

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image frame:
Exception: Codec failed to produce an image, possibly due to invalid image data.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Image provider:
NetworkImage("https://capture-bigmountain.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/upload/BYWHLKHLlmMgcZA89493205981758583.jpeg",
scale: 1.0)
Image key:
NetworkImage("https://capture-bigmountain.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/upload/BYWHLKHLlmMgcZA89493205981758583.jpeg",
scale: 1.0)

================================================================

code

```
class PhotoGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const PhotoGrid({super.key, required this.index, required this.photo});
  final Photo photo;
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<PhotoScanBloc, PhotoScanState>(
        buildWhen: (previous, current) => previous != current,
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is PhotoScanLoaded) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                BlocProvider.of<PhotoScanBloc>(context)
                    .add(PhotoPurchaseEvent(photoIndex: index));
              },
              child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
                Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 0.5)),
                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: "https://capture-bigmountain.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/upload/BYWHLKHLlmMgcZA89493205981758583.jpeg",
                        //photo.url,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                        errorListener: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
                              color: ColorTheme.lightGreyColor,
                              child: const Center(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.error,
                                  color: ColorTheme.mainColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))),
                (photo.isInCarts)
                    ? Container(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                        child: Center(
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                            width: 20,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/icons/bag.webp",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )))
                    : Container(),
              ]),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: Icon(Icons.error));
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i'm new here. just added code

Comment: Your image url gives me: AccessDeniedAccess Denied9C043ZZ3EDTMMACKsf7lU2Osr+6plUye2c3yOTbcLlxXhPHX/MGzF33VD88q1SrXYtkC0isDrbO3BBP1S42nilEeW/I=
So I'm guessing the same happens for the flutter app. Check credentials needed to view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want use `NetworkImage` :

```
    Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: NetworkImage("set your url")
      )
  ),),
```

Or use this if you want `Image.network` without any provider :

```
Image.network("set your url")
```